# Which type of pan can you recommend for pan-frying tofu?

Tags: tofu, frying-pan

Which type of pan can you recommend for pan-frying tofu, stainless, aluminum, or carbon steel?

Answer (score 1):

Cast iron rules! but if i was to choose from the options you provided i would pick the heaviest / thickest one regardless of the material.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pan is the one you're most comfortable with.  Any of those materials can give you good results if used correctly, and you might even get away with cast-iron or nonstick cookware.

In fact, this is true for most cooking tasks. Exception: if the food will ruin your pan, as with acid on cast iron/carbon steel, and eggs with many materials, if not oiled enough.

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner, I'd recommend a non-stick pan, and a wide one. Otherwise, you're liable to have the crust on the fried tofu stick to the pan.  Most tofu is fairly delicate.

Two tips:
1. dry and press the tofu before frying it
2. do not crowd the pan.

If you're an experienced cook, see BobMcGee's answer.